# Custom help page for controller extension?

Tags: visualforce, help, helptext

I've got a custom object and a Visualforce page with a controller extension for that object.  I've replaced the object's help page with a Visualforce page so I can show documentation on how the object is used (various kinds of logging).

I'd like to surface the Visualforce help page in the controller extension page.  I realize I can do this by manually making a link to the VF page, but is there a Visualforce tag or tag property that does this by exposing the page I've already connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The Context Sensitive Help Setting is not pulled in by `tabStyle` or `standardController` attributes.

You can, however, make it appear in exactly the same place as the native Custom Object Help by taking advantage of the `help` property on an `apex:sectionHeader`
tag:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="MyObject__c">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Header" help="{!URLFOR($Page.MyObjectHelp)}" />
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Works great!  Didn't expect to find the property for that in the header.